# Successfully rewrites for HTTP but not form HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this in htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [QSA]

    # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

If I open `http://tld/index`, it rewrites to `https://tld/index.php` successfully.

But if I open `https://tld/index` it **does not rewrite** to `https://tld/index.php` and just shows me a "Not Found" page.

**What is wrong with my rewrite rules?**

UPDATE - my apache settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerName  dom.tld
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerName dom.tld

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/dom.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dom.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dom.tld/chain.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Instead of rewriting http to https, you should really use a redirect 301, and add HSTS headers for better measures

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for existence of `.php` file before adding `.php` for eavery request and keep redirect rule before `.php` rule.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Clear your browser before testing these changes.

Comment: There is always "Not found" page when I open https://tld/file  (but file.php exists)

Comment: ok then make sure `DocumentRoot` of SSL site is same as non-SSL one

Comment: yes, DocumentRoot is the same. Just rewriting is not working as expected.

Comment: No rewriting is no problem, above rules work fine. It is definitely your local config. Share your `VirtualHost` config in question

Comment: I added apache host settings.

Comment: That loos fine to me, So `https://tld/file.php` work fine and `https://tld/file` give 404?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112442/discussion-between-anubhava-and-peter).

Comment: I switched to chat